# Will NPC villagers contribute to public works projects?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Isabelle hinted that villagers could donate to public works projects but that they probably won't succeed without my input.

So I assume I'm definitely going to have to chip *some* in for this stuff to happen, but when she says that does she mean other flesh and bone players can also donate, or will my NPC villagers also donate a few bells?

Comment: Yep, they only donate about a handful of bells. (100's)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Other flesh and blood players *can* donate to public works projects, even people just visiting your town, not just other residents! Hope for rich friends!

Villagers *do* contribute towards public works projects, but the amount tends to be so negligible that you'll still end up paying for the majority of the project yourself. They do this automatically, and there's no dialogue option to engage or encourage them to do so.

Comment: It should be noted that the animals nor other visitors can donate to the museum either.

Comment: After several public Works projects I'd estimate villagers generally donate somewhere between 100-600 bells per day, meaning it would take weeks for them to fund even the cheapest projects.

Answer (score 2):

In my town, the NPCs donate somewhere between 100 to 550 bells a day, but only after I've paid around 6000 bells to the project. Whether it works off a percentage of what you've paid, I'm not sure, but I think that's how it works.

Comment: I've had 'em donate before I've paid a single bell

Answer (score 1):

Isabelle is most likely hinting towards the fact that NPC villagers can tell the mayor which public works project they want the player to have built.

Even with Isabelle announcing that NPC villagers love to have projects created faster- the game consists of Wi-Fi friends and the player donating and the NPC's hardly, if ever, give any to the projects.

Answer (score 1):

NPC Villagers will donate to projects.

In my experience they may as well save their bells to randomly buy something off me because really, their help is nothing.

You will at most save 1,000 bells on a public works project due to villager aid. Do not expect this to happen because it very well may not.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is very different. In fact I have a public works project that's been in progress for 10 days, and I haven't donated a single Bell, yet there's already 20,000 Bells donated by NPC villagers towards the project.

Comment: So you are saying you raised 20k from Villagers?

Comment: I would suspect that they donate more the older the project. Just to ensure that things do finish if you at least give it enough time

Answer (score -1):

Well, they do contribute, but its hardly any so it's best to just get people over to your town to donate.

Comment: Please make your answers more thorough. But we all make mistakes, so be more detailed next time! Best wishes! ;)

Answer (score -1):

I do agree with the before held statement that it works on a percentage, however I think there is a cap.  I have had days of not contributing more than 1,000 bells and had around 50 bells off the villagers.  However when I contribute a bulk of around 20,000 bells on a good day it still averages about 350 bells.  You might want to look more into this, however if you are thinking of starting a public works project you should be prepared to pay for the majority of it yourself.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, from my experience, villagers contribute to public works projects, but the amounts are very small, from 100 to 600 bells, meaning you still have to pay for most of the project.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure but it could depend on what project is being built. I'm saying this because typically my villagers seem to donate anywhere from 50-150 a day.

However, I'm currently building a wind turbine and they've donated about 12,000 in 9 days. It's very inconsistent. A couple days it will only be 100 or so a day, then it'll spike anywhere from 1000 to a few thousand one day.

I know the wind turbine is considered a "desirable" PWP, it apparently helps with maintaining perfect town status. So I wonder if that has anything to do with it. I'll also say this is the first time I haven't paid off the entire fund immediately after setting up the PWP, so it could also be proportionate to how much you've donated? Or it could just be completely random. I'll post again after my next PWP and see if the trend continues.

Comment: There are couple points that I want to say. First, if you don't have a good and proper answer, just don't answer until you have it. Second, you should really do a better effort of making your post clearer. I did it for you this time but try to do better next time.